# VSTS 2010 Create a custom Process Template

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I am required to create a custom Process Template on using VSTS 2010 Beta 1. Given that I did not use templates in VSTS 2008 I am not even sure where to start. The TFS and VS 2010 are all installed and configured.

First I tried to create a test project and selected a built-in template "MSF for Agile Software etc." I wanted to try to modify (customize) it to begin with but was not sure how to do it. I searched high and low but could not find a sample/walkthrough/hint/help on how to develop a process template from scratch.  Sorry for the messy explanation but I am kind of VERY frustrated...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by going to Process Template Manager on your collection of the projects (*right click on collection in TFS explorer, Team foundation server settings -> Process Template Manager*)

Select template you want to modify and click download button. Rename and modify on your local system and upload with the same tool again to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Correct link to Team Foundation Server Power Tools August 2011: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Install this, then you can go to Tools -> Process Editor in Visual Studio.  Here is a tutorial for getting started: http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2011/1/how-to-customize-tfs-2010-work-items-and-workflows/

Comment: To keep this properly updated, here is the most recent version of the TFS Power Tools: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Comment: Still in power tools with VS TFS 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can use the witadmin tool: [Customizing and Managing Work Item Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129(VS.100).aspx)

Basically what you do is:

1. witadmin exportwitd ...
2. Edit the exported xml file
3. witadmin importwitd ...

Or you can install Team Foundation Server Power Tools. In this case, the operations above can be performed from Visual Studio, in Tools -> Process Editor:

1. Work Item Types -> Export WIT
2. Process Templates -> Open Process Template
3. Work Item Types -> Import WIT

Answer (score 0):

Power Tools is what you are looking for
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3e8c9b68-6e39-4577-b9b7-78489b5cb1da

Answer (score 0):

You can find very detailed video on how to do everything, see the following link:
http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/customize-tfs-process-2010-video/